# Axis label offset in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, plane

I have an application where there are two axes on a Cartesian plane, with their origin centered near the middle of the containing element. The d3.axis function is great, but the labels at each tick are fixed in that place, basically where the axes intersect at the origin, the 0's are intersected by the axis line.

Is there a way to get the numbers at each axis tick to be offset a little bit, so I don't get this problem?

Answer (score 1):

[`axis.tickPadding()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickPadding)